# Meine Aussprache von Wörtern endend auf "en" (mit einem Verschlusslaut davor)

Tags: pronunciation

Meine Muttersprache ist Deutsch und ich wundere mich über meine Aussprache von Wörtern, die mit einem Verschlusslaut und darauf folgend "en" enden. Beispiele mit allen Verschlusslauten wären "[retten](https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/retten)", "[reden](https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/reden)", "[packen](https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/packen)", "[legen](https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/legen)", "[kippen](https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/kippen)" und "[leben](https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/leben)".

Ich habe im Internet nachgeguckt, aber meistens sehe ich die Aussprache so beschrieben, dass aus dem "en" ein *n̩* wird. Aus "reden" wird somit *ˈʁeːdn̩* (wie auch immer das "r" realisiert sein mag). Das "en" verliert also seinen Vokal und das "n" wird als eigene Silbe betrachtet. Dazu siehe jeweils die beigefügten Wiktionary Links. Auch zu sehen war, dass nach "k" und "g" aus dem "en" ein *ŋ̍* werden kann und nach "p" und "b" ein *m̩* (das ist aber frei). Das mag zwar vielleicht die "korrekte" Aussprache sein, aber es kommt dem, was ich mache, nicht sehr nah.

Dann habe ich auch in hier in einem [Reddit-Beitrag](https://amp.reddit.com/r/German/comments/brhlie/pronunciation_of_ten_den_suffixes/) gesehen, wie aus dem Verschlusslaut ein glottaler Verschlusslaut wird. Somit wird aus "reden" einfach *ˈʁeːʔn̩* (oder so ähnlich). Mit meinem eigenen Sprachgefühl kann ich das auch teilweise bestätigen. Für mich fühlt sich diese Methode bei Wörtern wie "retten", "packen" und "kippen" noch einigermaßen natürlich an, aber bei Wörtern wie "reden", "legen" und "leben" eher weniger (das finale "n" passt sich hier wieder dem Verschlusslaut von davor an und kann *n*, *ŋ* oder *m* sein). Ich mach es aber noch ein wenig anders, aber es kommt dem schon etwas näher.

Nach ein wenig Experimentieren bin ich zu dem Schluss gekommen, dass ich zur Aussprache zuerst mit der Zunge oder den Lippen den Luftweg durch den Mund blockiere. Das heißt also, dass zuerst eine *n*, *ŋ* oder *m* Position eingenommen wird, die zwar den Luftweg durch den Mund blockiert, aber noch nicht durch die Nase. Danach wäre es zwar möglich, mithilfe eines glottalen Verschlusslautes den Luftweg auch durch die Nase zu blockieren und wieder freizulassen, um den Verschlusslaut ("t", "d", "k", "g", "p" oder "b") zu ersetzen, aber ich mach es ein wenig anders. Ich habe einmal versucht, mit dem Finger zu fühlen, was genau passiert, und ich denke, dass sich das Gaumensegel ein wenig nach hinten bewegt und mit der Rachenhinterwand Kontakt macht und so eben der Luftweg durch die Nase blockiert und wieder freigelassen werden kann. Dies dürfte auch zur Beobachtung passen, dass ich zwar einen glottalen Verschlusslaut in kompletter Isolation ausführen kann (da dieser beide Atemwege blockiert), aber den gefragten Laut nur bei verschlossenem Atemweg durch den Mund (da das Gaumensegel nur den Atemweg durch die Nase blockiert). [Hier](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaumensegel) findet sich noch eine passende Illustration. Wer versuchten möchte, es nachzumachen, der könnte versuchen, bei geschlossenem Mund ein Schnarchen nachzuahmen, nur dass der Luftweg eben komplett verschlossen wird und nicht nur teilweise.

Wie oben schon beschrieben, bei "t" und "d" wird das "en" also zu *n̩*, bei "k" und "g" zu *ŋ̍* und bei "p" und "b" zu *m̩*. Es muss auch nicht immer das "en" am Ende sein. Bei Wörtern wie "lebenden" klingt es für mich am natürlichsten, wenn ich das Beschriebende mit der zweiten Silbe mache und die dritte Silbe unverändert mit Vokal ausspreche. Bei Wörtern endend auf "em" verhält es sich ähnlich, dass ich sie wie mit "en" ausspreche, nur dass ich nach der Aussprache des Verschlusslautes direkt in die *m* Position wechsle, was für "p" und "b" natürlich nicht notwendig ist.

Meine Fragen:

- Gibt es für diesen Laut irgendein IPA-Symbol oder hat dieser Laut eine eigene Bezeichnung?
- Wie häufig ist diese Aussprache und in welchen Regionen ist diese verbreitet?
- Wie ist die Häufigkeit und Ausbreitung verglichen mit der "korrekten" Aussprache und der Aussprache mit dem glottalen Verschlusslaut?

Übrigens lebe ich in Niedersachsen, ziemlich weit im Westen, falls das eine Rolle spielt.

Eine Liste mit allen IPA-Symbolen lässt sich [hier](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) finden (auch unter "Extensions" gucken). Laut meinen Vermutungen könnte es sich unter der erweiterten Liste um einen "velopharyngeal plosive" handeln, aber das Problem ist, dass dieser nur als "trill" und "fricative" aufgeführt ist und das Kästchen bei "plosive" dunkelgrau gefärbt ist, also dass es scheinbar eigentlich nicht möglich ist, soetwas auszusprechen? [Hier](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velopharyngeal_consonant) findet sich noch ein Artikel zu den "velopharyngeal consonants".

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. Not sure if you know about it - you can ask your question in German as well (question about the same topic are handled as "unique" for each language asked in).  I would separate the question(s) more visually to make clear "context wall, question, note".

Comment: @Shegit Brahm Hello, not sure what exactly you mean. Do you mean that I can ask the same question again but just in German, so that there are two posts? I just thought that asking in English would make the question more accessible to more people.

Comment: sorry for confusion. Es ist jedem freigestellt, welche Sprache benutzt wird. Nein, es ist keine Ermunterung, einfach so die gleiche Frage in einer anderen Sprache zu stellen. Duplikate werden geschlossen - außer sie sind in einer anderen Sprache. Welche Sprache dem Publikum hier zugänglicher ist, ist mir unbekannt.

Comment: @Shegit Brahm Hm bin mir noch nicht ganz sicher, ob ich hier etwas grundlegend nicht verstehe. Erst sagst du, dass das keine Ermunterung sein solle, die gleiche Frage in einer anderen Sprache zu stellen, und dass Duplikate geschlossen werden, aber dann sagst du, "außer sie sind in einer anderen Sprache". Also heißt das, dass es zwar erlaubt ist, aber du mich nicht dazu ermuntern, sondern nur darauf hinweisen willst?

Comment: Hallo! Wenn Du die Frage bewusst auf Englisch gestellt hast, um auch Linguisten zu erreichen, die nicht gut oder nicht gerne Deutsch lesen oder schreiben, ist das völlig in Ordnung. Ich denke, @ShegitBrahm wollte nur vermeiden, dass Du nur deshalb Englisch benutzt, weil Du denkst, das sei hier gefordert.

Comment: Die Bemerkung zu den Duplikaten war in der Tat durch die Präzisierung etwas verwirrend, aber Du sollst die Frage nicht doppelt stellen. Die erwähnte Ausnahmeregelung ist nur dazu da, einen Fragesteller nicht auf ein Duplikat zu verweisen, dass er nicht lesen kann.

Comment: @Carsten S Ah verstehe jetzt, danke.

Comment: Zur Frage, welche Sprache hier mehr Leute erreicht: Das ist Deutsch. Dies hier ist ein Forum über die deutsche Sprache. Daher ist anzunehmen, dass (fast) alle, die diese Seite besuchen, Deutsch zumindest auf einem Anfängerniveau sprechen. Über andere Sprachen kann man hingegen keine Annahmen treffen. Insbesondere kann ich nicht nachvollziehen, warum viele Leute glauben, hier würden alle Englisch sprechen. Es gibt auch Menschen, die Deutsch lernen wollen, deren Muttersprache Arabaisch, Russisch, Koreanisch oder Italienisch ist, und die kein Wort Englisch können. ...

Comment: ... Ich habe vor 2 oder 3 Jahren mal ausgewertet, wieviele Antworten von deutschen Muttersprachlern verfasst wurden, das waren damals ca. 95% alle Antworten. Nur 5% aller Antworten stammten von Leuten, die eine andere Muttersprache hatten, oder bei denen ich die Muttersprache nicht feststellen konnte.

Comment: Zu diesen Fakten kommt hinzu, dass hier gewünscht wird, alle Kommentare und vor allem auch alle Antworten in jener Sprache zu verfassen, in der die Frage gestellt wurde. Und dann tritt häufig eben die völlig absurde Situation ein, dass sich ausschließlich Menschen, deren Muttersprache Deutsch ist, über ihre eigene Muttersprache in einer Fremdsprache unterhalten. **Das ist nicht wünschenswert!** Daher ersuche ich immer wieder alle deutsche Muttersprachler die Fragen, die sie über ihre eigene Muttersprache haben in ihrer eigenen Muttersprache, also auf Deutsch, zu stellen.

Comment: Und solange es noch keine Antworten gibt, spricht auch nichts dagegen, eine auf Englisch gestellte Sprache in jene Sprache zu übersetzen, mit der man mehr Antwortschreiber erreicht. Denn zumindest ich beantworte lieber Fragen, die auf Deutsch gestellt wurden. Denn Englisch beherrsche ich leider nicht auf demselben Niveau wie Deutsch, und das trifft hier auf viele Antwortschreiber zu.

Comment: Anderes Thema: *"I'm a native speaker":* Das trifft auf jeden Menschen zu der irgend eine Sprache sprechen kann, egal, welche Muttersprache jemand spricht. Solange man nicht dazusagt, von welcher Sprache man ein Muttersprachler ist, stellt die Aussage, man sei Muttersprachler, dem Leser keine hilfreichen Informationen zur Verfügung. Vor allem, wenn man diese Aussage in einer anderen Sprache als der Muttersprache macht. Das verwirrt eher als dass es hilft.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast Na gut, 95% ist natürlich schon ziemlich hoch und mehr als ich erwartet hätte. Und jetzt, wo Du es sagst, ist es natürlich etwas seltsam, sich über seine eigene Sprache in einer Fremdsprache zu unterhalten. Ich werde mich später mal damit beschäftigen, das Ganze umzuschreiben. Ohnehin sind die ganzen Kommentare auch schon ins Deutsche abgerutscht, auch wenn sie wenig zu dem eigentlichen Thema beitragen.

Comment: @Orbit: Ich habe die Fragen als solche hervorgehoben. Ein gescheiter Titel fiel mir noch nicht sein - denn der aktuelle klingt für mich noch nicht nach einem "such/findbaren" Thema/Inhalt. Das die Schilderung aus der Ego-Perspektive ist, ist völlig iO. Nachfrage zur Eigenrecherche: Gibt es denn eine vollständige Liste an IPA-Zeichen? Und ist da irgendwas ähnliches/verwandtes dabei?

Comment: @Shegit Brahm Du kannst einmal hier (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) das Diagramm sehen und unter extensions die Erweiterungen. Ich bin da auch schon alles einmal durchgegangen, was mir wichtig erscheint, aber noch nichts gefunden. Mit vielem davon kann ich auch wirklich nichts anfangen, ich bin da wirklich kein Experte. Ich wundere mich über den downvote, aber ohne einen Kommentar weiß ich natürlich nicht, wie ich die Frage verbessern kann.

Comment: Ich bin nach weiterer Nachforschung auch schon auf die Vermutung gekommen, dass sich das Gaumensegel nach hinten bewegt und Kontakt mit der Rachenhinterwand macht. Wie soll ich die Frage am besten bearbeiten? Einfach als Ergänzung nach unten schreiben oder den ganzen Block abändern?

Comment: @Orbit: Meine Frage zielt indirekt darauf, dass (taugliche) Quellen der Eigenrecherche und warum die Fundstellen die eigene Frage unbeantwortet lassen, integriert werden. Z.B. den Link mit eventuellen Kandidaten und warum sie nichts taugen. Eine Seite mit Mustern "Bewegung Zunge/Kehlkopf etc bei der Lauterzeugung" & welche selbst beobachtete Bewegung vonstatten geht. Ich habe inhaltlich zur Frage 0 Ahnung. Mir geht es meta darum, wie m.E. hier auf SE die eigene Recherche gewünscht wird. Ich finde die Selbstbeschreibung ziemlich gut - und denke, dass die "offiziell erfassten" Referenzen bilden

Comment: Die Frage sollte sich nach der Änderung so lesen, als sei sie vollständig und mehr oder minder aus einem Guss. Weil in 5 Jahren sich keiner die Mühe macht, irgendeine "Entwicklung" der Frage zu verstehen. Was halt hilft ist "gefunden habe ich x, passt nicht weil y". Und bei Links den relevanten Teil zitieren, der Linkinhalt kann verloren gehen. Soll heißen: keinerlei negative Kritik, dass dies und das fehlt. Sondern nur meine Meinung, dass zwar vordergründig viel beschrieben ist, jedoch die ganze eigene Leistung/Quintessenz zur Eigenrecherche ... unsichtbar ist.

Comment: @Shegit Brahm Ich hoffe, jetzt ist es ein wenig vollständiger und transparenter. Ich bin mir bei den Zitaten aber noch nicht ganz sicher, weil diese auf englisch sind, und wie sollte ich das mit den Bildern machen, hier extra hochladen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zu den drei Fragen:

1. Dieser Laut, den du sehr treffend beschrieben hast, ist der **nasale Release** eines Plosivs. Im IPA wird er durch ein kleines, hochgestelltes <ⁿ> nach dem jeweiligen Verschlusslaut bezeichnet. Das Wort «Laden» würde also als [ˈlaːdⁿn̩] geschrieben, «Wagen» als [ˈʋaːɡⁿŋ̩], «Laken» als [ˈlaːkⁿŋ̩] (oder, falls aspiriert, als [ˈlaːkⁿʰŋ̩]), «Leben» als [ˈleːbⁿm̩] u.s.w. Normalerweise bleibt der nasale Release unbezeichnet, denn eine Artikulation von homorganen Folgen wie [dn], [kŋ] u.s.w. wird ganz natürlich mit einem nasalen Release artikuliert. Der glottale Release würde übrigens, streng genommen, in Koartikulation mit dem entsprechenden Plosiv artikuliert, der in diesem Fall aber keinen Release hätte, also beispielsweise [ˈlaːd̚͡ʔn̩].
2. Einen Übersicht der verschiedenen Releasearten ist zu finden in der Karte [Realisierung von /t/ in *Daten* und *warten*](http://prowiki.ids-mannheim.de/bin/view/AADG/TenAuslaut) des Atlas zur Aussprache des deutschen Gebrauchsstandards (AADG).
3. Ich vermute, dass in der präskriptiven Bühnenaussprache der nasale Release nicht verwendet werden sollte, und dass stattdessen für ein Wort wie «reden» die Aussprache [ˈreːdən] oder [ˈreːdɛn] vorgeschrieben würde. Eine solche Aussprache wäre allerdings sehr unnatürlich ausser vielleicht in der Schweiz.

Comment: Wie verhält sich das zum Stimmhaften Uvulare  Nasal "... ein in den Sprachen der Welt selten vorkommender stimmhafter Konsonant, bei dessen Artikulation der Luftstrom im Mund durch einen Verschluss am Gaumenzäpfchen blockiert wird und stattdessen durch die Nase entweicht (sodass eben ein Nasalkonsonant entsteht)."?